# CVS revision merge

Tags: cvs

This question is about simplifying the revision history, not simply merging two versions together in an output file.

Let say I have a lot of revisions on a specific file because the way we worked for many years was to automatically create a revision each time we saved a file to disk. So a developper saving 100 times in a day, created 100 revisions of that file that day. I would like to recreate a new/simplified "CVS revision list" to have a single revision per day. The idea is to make a better revision history before moving to GIT eventually.

I could checkout each file one one by and specifying the date and recreate a new CVS repository this way, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way to "remove/combine" revisions in CVS.

For example, if I have these revisions for a specific file in a day:
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
...
1.1000

I could end up with only
1.1 and 1.000 (All other intermediate revisions would be merged in the history into revision 1.1000

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cvs admin` to permanently remove versions of the files on the server. This will leave your version numbers unchanged, there will just be large holes between the numbering.

Of course you have to be careful because this is a permanent operation.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot !